# Use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to know how many network requests in 60 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have a `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` subclass that I use for API calls to an external service. They only allow 30 API calls per 60 seconds, so I need to make sure I keep track of how many I have used.

Is there a way to know each time I have made a request with the `operationManager` and then keep a timer going so I know how many requests have been made? Then reset the count after 60 seconds? Or should I just save an `NSDate` object and then check to see if it has been 60 seconds?